# Express.js - How can I call multiple params for search filter?

Tags: express

guys! I am looking how can I have multiple params in expressjs for search filter for eg.:

website.com/properties/London/maxRooms=5&garden=yes&parking=yes

for maxRooms, garden and parking

But sometimes I want to apply just a filter eg.:

website.com/properties/garden=yes

Do I have to write every GET for every param in separate lines?

like:

```
app.get('/properties/maxRooms=:max&garden=:garden&parking=:parking', function (req, res) {

})

app.get('/properties/garden=:garden', function (req, res) {

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look over `body-praser`

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

`
This is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on body-parser.

Returns middleware that only parses JSON and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body), or an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type was not matched, or an error occurred.
`

Essentially, put "/properties/*" and do a middleware that checks for your req.params or req.body.params ;

Like in `app.get('/prooperties/*', (req, res) => {
// params will came as an array of objects if i remember righht, please check body-parser
req.body.params
});`

or in `app.get('/properties/maxRooms*'....
req.body.params
);`

But if you are using a JSON supported language or you can submit an entire form, avoid url params.